# Why does this CSS not work in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, css

I have spent literally hours trying to work this out - so it's time to ask.

I'm told that for something to have `height: x%` (a height as a percentage) it's parent needs to have a height, as does it's parent, etc.

So here's my structure:

```css
html
  body
    div#wrapper
      div#viewer_wrapper
        iframe#viewer
```

And here's some applicable CSS:

```css
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
#wrapper{
    min-height: 100%; /*it's this that seems to trip me up - a fixed height works for the problem, but not for the layout obviously*/
    position: relative;
}
#viewer_wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#viewer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 96%;
}
```

Chrome is very obedient - even without the `height:100%` on `#viewer_wrapper`, I have no problem. But on Firefox and IE, the iframe refuses to take up 96% of the screen's height (what I want). I've even tried heaps of JS fixes, all of which lead to not only ugly code, but bad side effects.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try to create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so people can test it out.

Comment: @Passerby since it's a question that'd require you to have the website open in a whole page, it's easier just to give the URL.

Comment: Yes (change the underscores to dots)

Comment: @DuncanNZ http://jsfiddle.net/QNFUc/ Because a fiddle allows others to test and share their code, while your website can not.

Comment: @Passerby how'd you make that fiddle, then? :p

Comment: @reisio I've already made one for OP. Check the link in my comment.

Comment: @Passerby exactly, so people can apparently make fiddles off his code despite it not having originated from a fiddle. :p

Comment: @reisio Exactly, so isn't it nice to make "yourself" code fiddlable so others can test and share? How can I make change on "your" website and illustrate to "you"? And what if you suddenly need to make change to "your" website before the question has been answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that what you want to do is split your #wrapper in two.

The top portion, containing everything but #viewer_wrapper, should have its natural height.  the bottom portion, containing #viewer_wrapper, should have height: 100%.

html

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    ...
</div>
<div id="wrapper2">     
    <div id="viewer_wrapper">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```css
#wrapper2 { height:100%; }
#wrapper, #wrapper2 {
    width:70%;
    position:relative;
    padding:4px 10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:whiteSmoke;
    border-left:2px solid black;
    border-right:2px solid black;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm amazed how challenging such a simple task proved to be - but your solution is logical.

Comment: There's a reason neither of the S's in CSS stands for "simple"... : P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its parents need to have a `height`, not a `min-height`.

Comment: How can I achieve this without breaking my layout?

Comment: I haven't seen your layout, but likely by replacing min-height for #wrapper with height.

Comment: having simply `height:100%;` does break my layout. The web address of my site is at the bottom of the question.

Comment: You realize the height even as it "works" in Chrome is going to be arbitrary based on the end user's browser window height. Why not just set a height in px that looks decent to you.

Comment: if I were to do that, I'd still want the iframe taking up the majority of the height of the page - as it contains a document that you read. And say the user's screen was smaller than the height (in pixels) that I gave - then they'd be scrolling up and down the document as well as the iframe just to read it's content. So a percentage seems very logical. Just so hard :/ (although it shouldn't be)

Comment: Well, as I said, it's arbitrary. If the browser window is somewhat short, they'll also be scrolling a lot. You can use JS to resize a frame so all of its vertical content will be shown at once. If you really want to go with your percentage approach (I wouldn't, same problem), look into the display: table(-*); values.

Answer (score 0):

As I have just understood what exactly you want to do, you can use something like this:

```
<div id="viewer_wrapper">
    <div id="top">Something on the top</div>
    <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
#viewer_wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    width: 100%;
    top: 200px; /* Some number that fits to the content on the top. */
    bottom: 0;
}
```

---

For me it works, both with 100% height and 96% height. But generally, it's better not to use `min-height`. Use `height` and `overflow: visible;` instead.  And note that `padding`s and `margin`s may be different so set them to a value (possible 0).

Also the `height` of `body` is a reason to make come content of your page, like background, visible only above the fold.

Comment: *sigh* `height:100%; overflow:visible;` on `#wrapper` fixes the problem, but breaks my layout. Why is it so hard!?

Comment: It isn't that hard. This is the main challenge of Web Design, to make your markup work in all browsers. Have you tried adding an `overflow: visible;` and do that breaks your layout too? How, exactly, it messes your layout?

Comment: Because if you change `min-width:100%` to `width:100%`, when you scroll down, the white background that is behind the page content disappears.

Comment: So `overflow: visible;` should fix it.

Comment: @me I mean `min-height` and `height` (not `min-width` and `width`)

Comment: for some reason that doesn't seem to fix it for me

Comment: Oh, that's also because you set 100 percent height on your body. It fixes with removing it.

Comment: But then the `height:100%;` on the iframe doesn't work, since all of the iframes parents apparently must have a height set

Answer (score 0):

no point setting a min-height to 100%, that doesnt really make sense.

Instead you would use min/max heights like this:

```
#wrapper{
    min-height:50%;max-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Relative heights/widths used this way will only take up those sizes when forced to by the content. ie they will take up the min height unless the content expands the container, it will expand up to the max height value. The solution as you already alluded to is to set a fixed height, height:100% for example.

here's a fiddle with relative values, http://jsfiddle.net/zB2Za/
and a fiddle with the fix http://jsfiddle.net/zB2Za/2/

If you want the page contents to 'fill' the entire page, then set the margin and padding for the body to 0, this is shown in the second fiddle.

Comment: For my layout I want `#wrapper` to take up the entire page, otherwise it doesn't look right.

Comment: But if the page is bigger than 100% of the viewport then it breaks. If you go to my site, change `min-width:100%` to `width:100%` on `#wrapper` in your dev tools, and scroll down, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: you mean height right? change your max-height to height:100%; and add overflow-y:hidden; to highlight the issue, also add margin-bottom:10px;

Comment: Sorry yes I do mean height. Doing that seems to just cut off the page at the height of the screen. (it is `min-height` not `max-height`)

Comment: its a bit of a mess! haha another thing you can do is add position:absolute to your iframe style, and then add bottom:0 to position it that way. at the moment it fits 96% of its containing element, which already extends beyond the height of its container. very messy stuff. but this is what happens with relative heights...

Comment: move the wrapper div to surround everything, so it contains everything. Set its position to fixed with 100% width and height. getting closer...